# How do i enter a url in php using nano

Tags: php, url, nano

When I enter:

```
$site = "http://localhost";
```

everything after the double forward slash is commented out.  How do I prevent this?
*edit* Thank ya'll for helping. I think I should elaborate.  I am setting this variable so that I may use it in this code:

```
 if ($numrows == 1){
                          $site = "http://localhost";
                          $webmaster = "myemail@somemail.com"; //not my email
                          $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                          $subject = "Activate Your Account";
                          $message = "Thank you for registering! Click the link below to activate your account.\n";
                          $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                          $message .= "You must activate your account to log in.";

                          if(mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                          $errormsg = "You have been registered.  You must activate your account from the activation link sent to <b>$getemail</b>.";
                          $getuser = "";
                          $getemail = "";
                          }else
                          $errormsg = "An error has occurred. Your activation email was not sent.";
                      }else
                       $errormsg = "An error has occurred. Your account was not created.";
```

I think the problem may be that my localhost isn't set up to send email.  Would this work if the page were actually on the web and I used a real URL for the "$site" variable?

Comment: nano probably needs to be made php-aware... no idea how to do that.

Comment: Code will work in local also in production.  Nano identifiees // as comment but only for display purposes. Execution is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick but output will be affected, so it is not a solution:

```
$site = "http:\/\/localhost";
```

Then you can try:

```
$site = "http:"."/"."/"."localhost";
```

or also:

```
$site = "http:".chr(47).chr(47)."localhost";
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

To my best understanding, you wish to use the `$site` variable as a link within your page, eg:

```
    <?php
    $site = "http://localhost";
    echo "<a href=\"$site\">sites</a>";
    ?>
```

There doesn't seem to be any trouble with your line of code over here as far as my localhost server is concerned. It could be that you are not escaping something properly, like in the case of my `echo` statement, were I had to backslash my quote.

Comment: The problem of Leggendario is not PHP since the nano editor marks all as comment when it detects "//" characters.  Code is 100% executable in PHP but if you don't want to see as nano comment, a trick is needed, like isolate each "/" and concatenate them, or represent with chr(47) .  Regards

Comment: am just going to stay here reading, cause i don't really do nano, sublime has always been fine for me as an editor...

Answer (score 0):

In PHP double quotes indicate the text should be processed.

So

```
$v = 1;
echo "$v";
```

will give: 1

but if you

```
echo '$v';
```

You'll get: $v

Try doing:

```
$site = 'http://localhost';
```